How to use OpenSeaMap via MapsUI in Maui App
I have a big problem try to render and use OpenSeaMap in may Maui App.
I use MapsUI and Brutile to try rendering OpenSeaMap inside my App written in Maui but without success.
I don’t know why, I follow all the article and tips but I don’t find nothing useful. The result is always a blank page with zoom control.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Please show us what you’re doing if you expect us to help you

Try to attach a logger https://mapsui.com/documentation/logging.html and use a tool like fiddler to see how the request fails.

Ok I do it. I post the answer for everyone have the same issue.
var map =  new Mapsui.UI.Maui.MapControl();
map?.Layers.Add(new TileLayer(CreateSeaMapsTileSource()));
GlobalSphericalMercator tileSchema = new GlobalSphericalMercator();
string[] serverNodes = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c" };
Attribution openStreetMapAttribution = OpenSeaMapAttribution;
return new HttpTileSource(tileSchema,          "https://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", serverNodes, null,   "OpenSeaMap", DefaultCache, null, openStreetMapAttribution);

